# The databases in /usr/share/applications cannot be updated

Tags: linux-kernel, mime-types, ubuntu-20.04, file-association

I have created a .desktop file under the location /usr/share/applications. Now to update the database If I run the command: update-desktop-database /usr/share/applications, then it does not update the database and says:

```
The databases in /usr/share/applications cannot be updated
```

I have tried logging out and in again, but it still does not work.

I have tried these links, but they don't work for me.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192204
https://askubuntu.com/questions/434269/unity-launcher-wont-update-the-shortcuts-after-update-desktop-database-only-af

Comment: `sudo update-desktop-database` per chance?